# How do I determine which report section a value or label belongs to in an IXBRL/XBRL File?

Tags: c#, xsd, xbrl

I'm trying to build a model for filed company accounts using html/ixbrl files publicly available from UK CompaniesHouse website. The problem I have is that the label values in each taxonomy reports( Income statement, director report, audit report etc) are not unique across the taxonomy. Many values appear in multiple reports and given an ix Node in the screenshot further below this, I'm not sure how to determine which one it is.

For example **Bank borrowings and overdrafts** appears four times across different report in the taxonomy. ( Taxonomy on my github along with a sample ixbrl file here https://github.com/MangoCrusher/xbrldemo1 )

Referring to the screenshot below, how do I determine which report of the taxonomy the highlighted Current Assets node belongs to?

[image]

This is what my taxonomy dictionary looks like so far looks like which I have been able to populate with values extracted from various xsds and xmls found in the taxonomy bundle ( item 0 to 14 are various sections that may be found in a typical report). The idea is to match the ixnodes to the dictionary keys and recreate the financial statement in full, if I could figure out how to take an ixnode and tell which report the item belongs to. Using the uk-core attribute I cannot get to the specific xsd file in the taxonomy but not to the actual report .

[image: model image]

Thank you

Comment: I guess the answer is that it appears in all of them. There is no distinction - a concept can appear multiple times in the presentation linkbase. You might also find the same tag appears multiple times in the accounts, as e.g. that current assets figure might appear on the balance sheet & as the total in the related note.

Comment: thanks, so that would mean that while I can look at an IXBRL file and clearly see what values belong to which section visually , it won't be possible to take an IXBRL file and recreate the whole financial report "programmatically?" as I just won't know which section to place the concept, e.g. Assets in?